# Prove the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-q$ is irreducible in $F_p[x]$?

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers such that $p$ is not a quadratic residue mod $q$. Show that if $pq=-1$ mod $4$ then the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-q$ is irreducible in $F_p[x]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $pq\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. Then by Quadratic Reciprocity we have that the Legendre symbols $(p/q)$ and $(q/p)$ are equal. This is because if $pq\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, then $p$ and $q$ cannot be both congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$.

So if $p$ is not a QR modulo $q$, then $q$ is not a QR modulo $p$.

But then $x^2-q\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ does not have a solution. If $x^2-q$ were reducible, then it would be expressible as a product of linear factors, and  therefore the congruence $x^2-q\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ would have a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see why the law of Quadratic Reciprocity implies the Legendre symbols are equal.

Comment: Recall that $(p/q)=(q/p)$ **unless** $p$ and $q$ are **both** congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$. But if they were both congruent to $-1$ mod $4$, their product would be congruent to $1$. We were told that their product is congruent to $-1$.  In effect we were told that one of $p$ or $q$ is congruent to $1$ mod $4$ and the other is congruent to $-1$.

Comment: OK, thanks! I miscalculated with the formula.

Comment: You are welcome, I tend not to like the "formula" version of Reciprocity. It is easier to think that we can flip unless both primes are congruent to $-1$.